# How to apply CSS to list in HTML

Tags: html, css

I had to Create a working HTML/CSS for the following nestes list

```
   root
        child1
    child11
        child2
    child21
    child22
        child3
    child31
```

So for this I created the following

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-view">
            <li>
                    <ul><li>Chlid11</li></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Chlid21</li>
                        <li>Chlid22</li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Chlid31</li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Now How will I be able to apply CSS to the leaf parent and root node .

I have to make Leaf to green , parent to red and root should be like parent but with underline

Here Leaf are 
Child: 11 , 21, 22 , 31 
Parent: the three li 
root will be :the first ul

This was a question asked to me in an Interview I am just trying to solve it

Css has to be dynamic . I mean I was not suppose to add classes directly saying what is leaf and what is root .

Something like this

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r616k0ks/2/)

UPDATE

CSS

```
.list-view> li:first-child{

    color:red;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.list-view> li ul li {

    color:red;
}

.list-view> li ul li ul li{

    color:green;
}
```

I am not able to make just the root node underline 
Thanks

Comment: I had to read the question (and the title) 4 times before I give up reading ...

Comment: which nodes are leafs and which are parent?

Comment: there are only 2 levels, and you speak of 'root', 'parent' and 'leaf'. Could you be a bit more precise on what is what?

Comment: I guess Vikram is explaining in terms of Data structures. Leaf which has no branches, Parent is next to leaf and root is the top most.

Comment: If you would like to you can fork this snippet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpeMja  to describe what you are looking for.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree  How about this ? http://jsfiddle.net/r616k0ks/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your markup does not make very much sense to me. Nesting ul's inside li's is not very useful when the li's do not contain any other content. I suppose your markup should look more like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Root</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Parent</li>
            <li>Parent
                <ul>
                    <li>Leaf</li>
                    <li>Leaf</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Root</li>
</ul>
```

When it comes to targeting each level with css, you have a number of options. Adding classes to each level may seem the most straight forward, but it can be harder to maintain, and it is easier to make mistakes. Others have already demonstrated this technique, so I'll limit myself to a few alternatives:

option 1a:

```
ul { /* root + parent + leaf */ }
ul ul { /* parent + leaf */ }
ul ul ul { /* leaf */ }
```

option 1b:

```
li { /* root + parent + leaf */ }
li li { /* parent + leaf */ }
li li li { /* leaf */ }
```

option 2:

```
ul > li { /* root + parent + leaf */ }
ul > li > ul > li { /* parent + leaf */ }
ul > li > ul > li > ul > li { /* leaf */ }
```

That is basically it I guess, though you could come up with some variations. Option 1a and 1b are equivalent. Option 2 is more specific, and can be useful when trying to overwrite certain styles. It is considered good practice to keep your selectors as little specific as possible though. This way you can overwrite them easier later on, and your selectors do not get ridiculously long. It just keeps your code easier to read and maintain, so I would definitely go for option 1 in this case.

Note that this technique requires you to overwrite your styles. The styling you requested could ie. be achieved by doing something like this:

```
li {
    color:red;    
}
li span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
li li li {  
    color:green;
}
```

The pseudo classes you speak of in the comments (:nth-child, ...) are irrelevant here. They are meant for distinguishing between siblings, not for parent-child relations.

**edit:**
the `text-decoration` property is a bit tricky to overwrite. Have a look at the specs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

> Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is specified on one of its ancestors.

To solve this, you have to make sure the element with the `underline` is not the parent of the rest of your tree. Th easiest way is to put it in a `span` and apply the `underline` only to that:

http://jsfiddle.net/r616k0ks/3/

(I have updated my code samples above accordingly)

Comment: I created something similar , But not able to make only the ROot node underline  http://jsfiddle.net/r616k0ks/2/

Comment: @Pvara Waaow nice hack :D

Answer (score 2):

I am going to take a stab in the dark, so please don't shoot me if i jumped the gun. But here is my understanding of what he is talking about.

```
    <ul class="root">
        <li class="parent">
            <ul class="leaf">
                <li>Chlid11</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <ul class="leaf">
                <li>Chlid21</li>
                <li>Chlid22</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent">
            <ul class="leaf">
                <li>Chlid31</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

[CodePen for example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbYKQV)

Comment: no they had asked me write a generalized css that do not require me to add The classes directly on the element

Comment: That's an odd question.  If you want to generalize it, then just use plain `ul's` and `li's` instead of classes. The `nth-` selector is specific, so if you want the first child of the parent you would do `class:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: here is a FIddle i created I think it looks pretty near to the question . Only Problem is I am not able to underline only the Root node       http://jsfiddle.net/r616k0ks/2/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding classes to your html?
https://jsfiddle.net/w7tx52L5/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    Root
    <li class="parent">
        Parent1
        <ul class="child"><li>Chlid11</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        Parent2
        <ul class="child">
            <li>Chlid21</li>
            <li>Chlid22</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        Parent3
        <ul class="child">
            <li>Chlid31</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.root {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.parent {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}

.child {
    color: green;
}
```

**Edit**

from your comment it appears you need to use `:nth-child` selectors. That wasn't clear from your original question. try this css -

```
ul {    
    color: red; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red; 
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) > ul li:first-child {
color:green; 
}

ul li:nth-child(even) > ul li {
color: green; 
}
```

The workaround of `display: inline-block` and `width:100%` is because `text-decoration`  affects all nested elements as well. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration

Comment: They asked me to do this by using nth-child selector etc .. I know how to use the classes :D

Comment: Also the HTML here is invalid. A div cannot be a child of a `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Using some specific selectors you can create almost any selection without using classes on the child elements.

I don't know if this is what you're getting at:

```
/* Root */
.list-view { background: grey; }
/* First level li's */
.list-view > li { background: red; }
/* First level of ul's */
.list-view > li > ul { background: orange; }
/* Second level of li's */
.list-view > li > ul > li { background: purple; }
/* Second level of li's, first element */
.list-view ul > li:nth-child(1) { background: green; }
/* Second level of li's, all other elements */
.list-view ul > li:nth-child(1n+2) { background: blue; }
```

See link https://jsfiddle.net/6d3g3zLm/

If not, feel free to elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to the list elements as Geoffrey has shown in his answer. Then apply styling to the classes as you would any styling. If you don't know CSS or anything about how to style, I would suggest researching a little more before you ask these kinds of questions, as this stuff is relatively easy to learn if you put some time and effort into it. http://www.w3schools.com/css/